# Laptop keyboard stops functioning on contact with metal plating

Tags: laptop, keyboard

To explain in more detail:
My laptop a Lenovo G580 started self spamming a few months back, and no idea why.
The usual culprit was the '/' character. When this happens I can't type or click on a text area. But I can move the mouse pointer with the touchpad. The click interrupt just wasn't firing.
To stop the spamming I'd have to spam the space key and get a few minutes of reprieve.

Then a week ago the Laptop keyboard just stopped working. Yesterday, I noticed that the keyboard ribbon was not fully clipped to the connector. I managed to successfully clip it back on.

Now, the keyboard area on the Laptop has a  metal surface and this is where I believe the problem lies. 
When I clip the keyboard to its resting place the keyboard won't function but when I move the keyboard up and away from the metal plate it starts working as normal.

The keyboard fittings (the edges that fit into the "hole"/"gap") are also metallic. 
Could that be the cause of the problem? When there is contact there is a short or something? I'm not sure what's going as that didn't happen before. 
I must have screwed something up in the process.

Any ideas before I spend 30 quid on a replacement keyboard (assuming the keyboard is even the problem)?

And external keyboards work perfectly,

Thanks.

Comment: ""The usual culprit was the '/' character""  can you explain this better?  You said all the keys work normal, but what if it is still just some key(s) stuck?  Keys can be stuck and others will still operate, how many is based on the desgin of the curcuit stuff.  When grounded (touching the metal) which may or may not be "by design", then everything IS working, but some key is still spamming?  My idea here being that the original key spamming might still exist and that is filling the buffer and stopping operations?

Comment: I meant randomly the '/' just starts filling the input buffer. But the key isn't stuck. None of the keys are stuck. No idea why that is happening. When I get back I will try your suggestion to see if spamming is still the problem, but if it is then it means the spamming problem is a lot worse because as soon as I move the keyboard from the plating it starts working again. Still worth a shot